# Change side of sidebar (left/right) when custom post type is being used

Tags: wordpress

On my Wordpress website, my archive.php has a sidebar on the right side.

I'm using WP Download Manager plugin and the categories from this plugin also use the archive.php template file from my theme. But on these category pages, I want to show the sidebar on the left side (default side is left).

Right now, in my archive.php I have a custom code to call custom made sidebar in the sidebar area when WP Download Manager is being used:

```
//get the sidebar for support
                if ( 'wpdmpro' == get_post_type() ) {
                    echo '<aside class="sidebar sidebar_right smartphones_sidebar_active three alpha units" role="complementary" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar"><div class="inner_sidebar extralight-border">';
                        dynamic_sidebar( 'Support' );
                    echo '</div></aside>';
                }
```

Check http://wptest.alcadis.nl/downloads/was-105r/.
This is an example page with the sidebar on the right. I want it on the left side for this custom post type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest adding a new template called archive-wpdmpro.php.

Copy the contents of archive.php inside here and place the sidebar where you'd like it.

This will make it easier for any post type specific changes you intend to make in the future.

Then add a single-wpdmpro.php to change the sidebar on individual pages.

Comment: I could try that. But how do I force the plugin to use the archive-wpdmpro.php instead of the regular archive.php?

Comment: This is how template hierarchy works. Did you already try this? Read here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out. Archive-wpdmpro.php didn't work. I had to rename it to taxonomy-wpdmcategory.php